# ValueError: invalid fill value with a <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning

I am practising on a loan prediction practise problem and trying to fill missing values in my data. I obtained the data from [here](https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-loan-prediction-iii/). To complete this problem I am following this [tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/complete-tutorial-learn-data-science-python-scratch-2/).

You can find the entire code (*file name model.py*) I am using  and the data [here](https://github.com/Aniruddh-SK/Loan-Prediction-Problem) on GitHub.

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
df[['Loan_ID', 'Self_Employed', 'Education', 'LoanAmount']].head(10)
Out: 
    Loan_ID Self_Employed     Education  LoanAmount
0  LP001002            No      Graduate         NaN
1  LP001003            No      Graduate       128.0
2  LP001005           Yes      Graduate        66.0
3  LP001006            No  Not Graduate       120.0
4  LP001008            No      Graduate       141.0
5  LP001011           Yes      Graduate       267.0
6  LP001013            No  Not Graduate        95.0
7  LP001014            No      Graduate       158.0
8  LP001018            No      Graduate       168.0
9  LP001020            No      Graduate       349.0
```

**After the last line is executed (corresponds to line 60 in the model.py file)**

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aniruddh-SK/Loan-Prediction-Problem/master/train.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url) 
df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df['LoanAmount'].mean(), inplace=True)
df['Self_Employed'].fillna('No',inplace=True)

table = df.pivot_table(values='LoanAmount', index='Self_Employed' ,columns='Education', aggfunc=np.median)
# Define function to return value of this pivot_table
def fage(x):
 return table.loc[x['Self_Employed'],x['Education']]
# Replace missing values
df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df[df['LoanAmount'].isnull()].apply(fage, axis=1), inplace=True)
```

**I am getting this error** :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-5146e49c2460> in <module>()
----> 1 df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df[df['LoanAmount'].isnull()].apply(fage, axis=1), inplace=True)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in fillna(self, value, method, axis, inplace, limit, downcast, **kwargs)
   2368                                           axis=axis, inplace=inplace,
   2369                                           limit=limit, downcast=downcast,
-> 2370                                           **kwargs)
   2371 
   2372     @Appender(generic._shared_docs['shift'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in fillna(self, value, method, axis, inplace, limit, downcast)
   3264                 else:
   3265                     raise ValueError("invalid fill value with a %s" %
-> 3266                                      type(value))
   3267 
   3268                 new_data = self._data.fillna(value=value, limit=limit,

ValueError: invalid fill value with a <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

How do I fill the missing values without getting this error?

Comment: `df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df[df['LoanAmount'].isnull()]` this doesn't make sense. You are seelcting the nulls and trying to fill the nulls with nulls?

Comment: @ayhan I followed it as it is in the tutorial and i think its supposed to be filling the missing values with true

Comment: Sorry it tries to fill with `df[df['LoanAmount'].isnull()].apply(fage, axis=1)`   Can you include the function fage definition and a small reproducible dataset?

Comment: @ayhan I have given the link to the entire code i am using  but just in case 
here it is def fage(x):
    ...:     return table.loc[x['Self_Employed'],x['Education']]

Comment: @ayhan as for the data set it is also on my github link in question the data is quite small u can download from there

Comment: Normally, the questions in Stack Overflow require a [MCVE]. It is better for everyone if the question is self-contained. We do not know what will happen to those links in the future.

Comment: @ayhan I would really welcome an edit for my question i am really bad at it  what changes should I make in the question

Comment: Sure I'll edit it when I am in front of a PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems author of tutorial want replace `NaN` by values of `table`.

But need first create `Series` by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for align data.

First remove replacing to `NaN` by `mean`:

```
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aniruddh-SK/Loan-Prediction-Problem/master/train.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url) #Reading the dataset in a dataframe using Pandas

#df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df['LoanAmount'].mean(), inplace=True)

df['Self_Employed'].fillna('No',inplace=True)
```

---

```
table = df.pivot_table(values='LoanAmount', 
                       index='Self_Employed', 
                       columns='Education', 
                       aggfunc=np.median)

print (table.unstack())
Education     Self_Employed
Graduate      No               130.0
              Yes              157.5
Not Graduate  No               113.0
              Yes              130.0
dtype: float64
```

---

```
#check all values with NaN in LoanAmount column
print (df.loc[df['LoanAmount'].isnull(), ['Self_Employed','Education', 'LoanAmount']])
    Self_Employed     Education  LoanAmount
0              No      Graduate         NaN
35             No      Graduate         NaN
63             No      Graduate         NaN
81            Yes      Graduate         NaN
95             No      Graduate         NaN
102            No      Graduate         NaN
103            No      Graduate         NaN
113           Yes      Graduate         NaN
127            No      Graduate         NaN
202            No  Not Graduate         NaN
284            No      Graduate         NaN
305            No  Not Graduate         NaN
322            No  Not Graduate         NaN
338            No  Not Graduate         NaN
387            No  Not Graduate         NaN
435            No      Graduate         NaN
437            No      Graduate         NaN
479            No      Graduate         NaN
524            No      Graduate         NaN
550           Yes      Graduate         NaN
551            No  Not Graduate         NaN
605            No  Not Graduate         NaN
```

---

```
#for check get all indexes where NaNs
idx = df.loc[df['LoanAmount'].isnull(), ['Self_Employed','Education', 'LoanAmount']].index
print (idx)
Int64Index([  0,  35,  63,  81,  95, 102, 103, 113, 127, 202, 284, 305, 322,
            338, 387, 435, 437, 479, 524, 550, 551, 605],

# Replace missing values
df = df.set_index(['Education','Self_Employed'])
df['LoanAmount'].fillna(table.unstack(), inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

```
#check output - filter only indexes where NaNs before
print (df.loc[df.index.isin(idx), ['Self_Employed','Education', 'LoanAmount']])
    Self_Employed     Education  LoanAmount
0              No      Graduate       130.0
35             No      Graduate       130.0
63             No      Graduate       130.0
81            Yes      Graduate       157.5
95             No      Graduate       130.0
102            No      Graduate       130.0
103            No      Graduate       130.0
113           Yes      Graduate       157.5
127            No      Graduate       130.0
202            No  Not Graduate       113.0
284            No      Graduate       130.0
305            No  Not Graduate       113.0
322            No  Not Graduate       113.0
338            No  Not Graduate       113.0
387            No  Not Graduate       113.0
435            No      Graduate       130.0
437            No      Graduate       130.0
479            No      Graduate       130.0
524            No      Graduate       130.0
550           Yes      Graduate       157.5
551            No  Not Graduate       113.0
605            No  Not Graduate       113.0
```

EDIT:

Better solution is [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) where replace `NaN` by `median`:

```
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aniruddh-SK/Loan-Prediction-Problem/master/train.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url) #Reading the dataset in a dataframe using Pandas

#df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df['LoanAmount'].mean(), inplace=True)

df['Self_Employed'].fillna('No',inplace=True)


print (df.loc[df['LoanAmount'].isnull(), ['Self_Employed','Education', 'LoanAmount']])
    Self_Employed     Education  LoanAmount
0              No      Graduate         NaN
35             No      Graduate         NaN
63             No      Graduate         NaN
81            Yes      Graduate         NaN
95             No      Graduate         NaN
102            No      Graduate         NaN
103            No      Graduate         NaN
113           Yes      Graduate         NaN
127            No      Graduate         NaN
202            No  Not Graduate         NaN
284            No      Graduate         NaN
305            No  Not Graduate         NaN
322            No  Not Graduate         NaN
338            No  Not Graduate         NaN
387            No  Not Graduate         NaN
435            No      Graduate         NaN
437            No      Graduate         NaN
479            No      Graduate         NaN
524            No      Graduate         NaN
550           Yes      Graduate         NaN
551            No  Not Graduate         NaN
605            No  Not Graduate         NaN
```

---

```
idx = df.loc[df['LoanAmount'].isnull(), ['Self_Employed','Education', 'LoanAmount']].index
print (idx)
Int64Index([  0,  35,  63,  81,  95, 102, 103, 113, 127, 202, 284, 305, 322,
            338, 387, 435, 437, 479, 524, 550, 551, 605],
           dtype='int64')

# Replace missing values
df['LoanAmount'] = df.groupby(['Education','Self_Employed'])['LoanAmount']
                     .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
```

---

```
print (df.loc[df.index.isin(idx), ['Self_Employed','Education', 'LoanAmount']])
    Self_Employed     Education  LoanAmount
0              No      Graduate       130.0
35             No      Graduate       130.0
63             No      Graduate       130.0
81            Yes      Graduate       157.5
95             No      Graduate       130.0
102            No      Graduate       130.0
103            No      Graduate       130.0
113           Yes      Graduate       157.5
127            No      Graduate       130.0
202            No  Not Graduate       113.0
284            No      Graduate       130.0
305            No  Not Graduate       113.0
322            No  Not Graduate       113.0
338            No  Not Graduate       113.0
387            No  Not Graduate       113.0
435            No      Graduate       130.0
437            No      Graduate       130.0
479            No      Graduate       130.0
524            No      Graduate       130.0
550           Yes      Graduate       157.5
551            No  Not Graduate       113.0
605            No  Not Graduate       113.0
```

EDIT:

There is another problem:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

And solution is replace `NaN`s:

```
df['Loan_Status'].fillna('No',inplace=True)
df['Credit_History'].fillna(0,inplace=True) 

outcome_var = 'Loan_Status'
model = LogisticRegression()
predictor_var = ['Credit_History']

classification_model(model, df, predictor_var,outcome_var)
```

Comment: Sure, but first dont forget comment `#df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df['LoanAmount'].mean(), inplace=True)`

Comment: do i also need to comment the fage(x) function for the pivot table

Comment: `fage` function only return 2 columns, but in my opinion is not necessary, so I omit it.

Comment: its working thanks but now i seem to be getting this error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 129, in <module>
    classification_model(model, df,predictor_var,outcome_var)
  File "model.py", line 96, in classification_model
    model.fit(data[predictors],data[outcome])

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 1173, in fit
    order="C")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 521, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 407, in check_array
    _assert_all_finite(array)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 58, in _assert_all_finite
    " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Comment: Ok, I think you have some `NaN`s in columns `predictors` or `outcome`. So need `df['predictors'].fillna('No',inplace=True)` and `df['outcome'].fillna('No',inplace=True)` for replace `NaN`s by some scalar, e.g. `0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146481/discussion-between-aniruddh-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('01_scratch_train.csv') # work with original data #

df['Self_Employed'].fillna('No', inplace=True)

table = df.pivot_table(values='LoanAmount', index='Self_Employed' ,columns='Education', aggfunc=np.median)

df.loc[df['LoanAmount'].isnull(), ['Self_Employed','Education', 'LoanAmount']]

def fage(x):
    return table.loc[x['Self_Employed'],x['Education']]


df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df[df['LoanAmount'].isnull()].apply(fage, axis=1), inplace=True)

df.loc[df['LoanAmount'].isnull(), ['Self_Employed','Education', 'LoanAmount']] # rechecking all values with NaN in LoanAmount column. No missing values.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. 
Here is the solution that worked for me,
The problem is you are trying to fill an empty selection, because you already do so with the mean:
**df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df['LoanAmount'].mean(), inplace=True)**

So when you select **df['LoanAmount'].isnull()** will result with an empty selection.
That why this line of code doesn't work: **df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df[df['LoanAmount'].isnull()].apply(fage, axis=1), inplace=True)**

Try to put an # in front of this line:  **df['LoanAmount'].fillna(df['LoanAmount'].mean(), inplace=True)**
The code should work after execution.